# C# Xamarin How to call a Method

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, void

I have a very very simple question I think.
I am a beginning student with C# Xamarin, and I was wondering:

How do I call a void in a void.

this is my first void:

```
public void DisplayEditDateFragment() {
    var fragmentContainer = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer);
    _fragment = new ProductInfoAdapter();
    var fragmentManager = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    fragmentManager.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, _fragment);
    fragmentManager.Commit();
    fragmentContainer.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; //Makes your fragment container visible if you set visibility=gone"
}
```

and this is my second:

```
public void ListViewProducts_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Set view to Info 
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProductInfo);

    //Give variables the right value to share with other classes
    ProductName = productsList[e.Position].ProductName;
    position = e.Position;
}
```

I want to execute the first void in the second, but how?

Comment: Just `DisplayEditDateFragment();`...

Comment: What is the problem when you call `DisplayEditDateFragment()` in your `ListViewProducts_ItemClick` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Diego Rafael Souza pointed out in the comments, you simply call it by its name, just as you would any other method.  Methods can be called within others methods.  Heck, a method can even be called within itself.

If I have 2 methods, `A` and `B`, I can call `B` from within `A`.  `A` will begin executing until it reaches the call to `B`.  `B` will then execute.  When `B` finishes, code flow will return to `A` and continue.  You would call `B` by simply typing `B()`.

I can also call `A` from within itself, which is known as using recursion.  With `A`, you simply type `A()`.  When this happens, `A` will begin executing until it reaches the call to `A`.  At this point, code flow will go to a new "instance" or "level" of `A` that will execute and either call `A` again or reach what is known as a "base case."  That's a quick explanation.  I'm sure you'll learn about recursion eventually.

You should get used to the idea of calling one method from another.  You'll find that organizing your code into methods is very helpful, so you'll be using them a lot.  Often times this means calling one method from within another.